# Error running a sql query in linux server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, shell

I ran the below query and it connects to the server but fails to execute the query, in spite of the table being available in database

```
$echo "select count(*) from TARGET049;" | sqlplus username/password@user_servername
```

error is displayed as below:

> SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Tue Mar 21 01:20:02 2017
>   Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select count(*) from TARGET050
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production

Please suggest on how to resolve this issue, i run the above cmd from one server to execute the sql query in a different server.

Comment: Is the table `TARGET049` or `TARGET050`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a here doc:

```
sqlplus username/password@user_servername << EOF
  select count(*) from TARGET049;
EOF
```

Comment: I have added the view name in query and now i have resolved the issue, thanks for your help

Comment: Table name is TARGET049